Old horror movie about a scientist building a device to stop death
I've a hazy recollection of seeing a short glimpse of a black and white horror movie on TV in the 1980's. The movie was old already then.
I believe it was about a researcher who built a device that somehow could prevent a human from dying even when the body would be broken, or even decapitated. The device was some kind of light projector and the death was trapped in it and become visible, as an entity, like Slimer in Ghostbusters.
This is all I can remember and I never did see the full movie. Was it a fever dream or a real movie?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Asphyx?

The Asphyx (1972)...?

English country squire Sir Hugo Cunningham searches for immortality by literally 'bottling up' the Spirit of the Dead, or Asphyx.

A 19th century English scientist named Hugo Cunningham uses special photographic equipment of his own design to take pictures of the dead. Through this, he becomes aware of the existence of asphyxes; spirits described in Greek mythology that come to take possession of people's bodies when they're about to die. He also determines that the light projected by his equipment not only makes asphyxes visible, but also restricts their movement, and that if you were to trap an individual's asphyx indefinitely, that person could no longer die unless their asphyx were released. This is shown to be true, even in instances where someone was crushed or beheaded.
When shown on-screen, the asphyxes do resemble Slimer from the Ghostbusters films. The film is in full colour, but that aside, it matches every other point in your description.




A somewhat misleading blurb.  Cunningham's path doesn't lead to death.

Thank you! Yes, this is it. It's in color but I probably did see it in an old black and white television.
